# WhirlyGlobe Framework - Rotate to coord

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i make the globe to rotate at a specific coordinate? I want to rotate the globe to a specific coordinate from URL. I managed to do it but only when the app is closed. When it is in background it simply moves to a location somewhere near the South Pole, no matter the coordinates i'm giving to it.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)moveToLocation
{
    WhirlyGlobe::GeoCoord startCoord;

    // If the app wasn started from URL
    if ([[GlobalValues sharedGlobalValues] enteredFromURL])
    {
        float lat = [[GlobalValues sharedGlobalValues] sharedLat];
        float lon = [[GlobalValues sharedGlobalValues] sharedLon];

        // Set the shared location
        startCoord = WhirlyGlobe::GeoCoord::CoordFromDegrees(lon, lat);
        // Calculate the rotation and make it
        Eigen::Quaternionf startLoc = [self.theView makeRotationToGeoCoord:startCoord keepNorthUp:YES];
        self.theView.delegate = [[[AnimateViewRotation alloc] initWithView:self.theView rot:startLoc howLong:5.0] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Also, how can i make it zoom? When the app starts from url it does the rotation+zoom but when it's in background it doesnt zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the AnimateViewRotation delegate around.  If it gets released behind the scenes the animation may disappear.

Also, I'd advise switching to the WhirlyGlobe Component if you can.  It's much simpler to use.

Comment: i'll try that, but the thing is that the globe is animating to a coordinate but only on one, no matter the coordinates i'm giving.

Comment: I'd suggest trying it out with some well known values.  Make sure it does what it should be doing and then look at the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Check method named 'animateToPosition' 
Example :

```
    [globeViewC animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(75.011509, 15.8377301) time:1.0];
```